# React PWA : create-react-app and Chrome's Lighthouse extension

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, create-react-app, lighthouse

I am new to React and starting with creating a new app with boilerplate code by using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). The tool works great and I can run the simple app locally.

Next, before I proceed, I want to ensure that it is a [Progressive Web App (PWA)](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/). From the latest release notes of create-react-app, looks like [create-react-app creates a PWA by default](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#making-a-progressive-web-app).

I have been using [Chrome's Lighthouse extension](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) to create a report showing whether all aspects of PWA have been achieved. But the report created against the default app created using create-react-app doesn't check off some important aspects of PWA, here's a snapshot :

[image]

Any guidance of creating PWAs with create-react-app would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create-React-App only enables the `sw-precache-plugin` in the production build. This is to avoid problems with caching when developing. You create a production build by running `npm run build` and then following the instructions in the terminal to serve the `build` folder.

Comment: Thanks Scott. For others, if you want to test locally with Lighthouse you can also just comment out the check for "process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'".